# java.util.logging.Logger log level is coming up as null

Tags: java, logging, weblogic, java.util.logging

I am running into logging issues after upgrading my Java EE app from Weblogic/JDeveloper to 12.1.2 to 12.1.3.

System.out.println is printing to the server log fine but log.info("test") is not.  The logging works if I set the log level e.g. log.setLevel(Level.INFO). Here are my test results.

```
// This works
System.out.println("test1");
// Output when run: test1

// This does not work. Nothing prints to the server log
log.info("test2");

// The above works if I set the log level
log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
log.info("test3");
// Output when run: test3

// This prints null. It appears that logging level is set to null on server startup
System.out.println(" what is my current logging level: " + log.getLevel());
```

As per Oracle documentation if no logging configuration is provided then the default logging.properties in JDK/JRE/Lib is used. The default log level is INFO.

I have also tried to load up logging.properties and switch log4j but nothing works.

I don't want to set log level to something in every class. Is there a way to set this on server startup or debug what is causing/setting the logging level to null.

Comment: How are you initializing log? That seems to be the problem. Also,  in your admin console, what does your `server -> logging tab` say the log level is set to. Check the advanced section.  You could add `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\mydomain\logging.properties` to your startWebLogic script as well

Comment: Here are my advanced log settings from admin console.                `Minimum severity to log: Notice`                                                                                                     `Log file :Severity level: Info`                                                        `Standard out :Severity level:  Notice`

Comment: I also tried -Djava.util.logging.config.file switch to startWeblogic script. It is not taking effective

Answer (score 0):

From the [logger documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLevel--):

> The result may be null, which means that this logger's effective level will be inherited from its parent.

So you only have to set the level of the root logger.  You should check that a [ConsoleHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) is installed and that the level is set to INFO or lower.  You should also check that writing to System.err shows up in the log file as that is the stream that is used for the ConsoleHandler.

Comment: I am assuming that logging.properties configuration will take care of loading root logger and installing console handler. I also read some where on the oracle site that if you don't provide any logging.properties then weblogic loads the logging.properties from jdk/jre. So, I think either way the server is supposed to pick up the default root logger and consolehandler from the one passed by -Djava.util.logging.config.file or one in jre.

Comment: Is a ConsoleHandler installed and the level is set to INFO?  Does System.err write to the log file?

Comment: System.err writes to the console/log file. ConsoleHandler is installed. This is what I have in the logging.properties                       `handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= INFO`

Comment: I also tried the below.    `handlers = weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler
weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler.level = ALL                         .level = ALL
 java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler.level = ALL`

Comment: Can you prove at runtime what the levels/filters of ConsoleHander and ServerLoggingHandler are using?

Comment: I have not tried serverlogginghandler but this is what I get for console handler.     `java.util.logging.Handler`

Comment: Your last comment about the console handler doesn't make sense to me.  Did you write Java code print System.out the values for what handlers are installed on what loggers and for each handler what is the level/filter?